# importing TFS project into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I have c:\inetput\wwwroot, and a project in TFS that (apparently ) maps to c:\projects\3.0\projectname. 
I want to import the project into c:\inetpub\wwwroot\projectname. 
If I create a new workspace in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\projectname and import the project, the physical file location is c:\projects\3.0\projectname. 
If I try to move it to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\projectname I keep getting error messages about overlapping workspaces and already contains a project named projectname.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `tf workfold -unmap` command to remove working folder mappings:

```
tf workfold /unmap [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl] [/workspace:workspacename] 
[/recursive] (serverfolder|localfolder) [/login:username,[password]]
```

Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753(v=vs.100).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fa04bx6(VS.100).aspx#